# javascript copy text to clipboard html5 and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched this question and there are so many ways that I cannot select from them.

Some of them are not supported any more. some are complicated.

I am looking for the simplest one for browsers supporting HTML5. I don't care if it is supported by old IE or not.

I prefer native javascript or Jquery. But plugins are fine too.

Comment: @Quentin that one is for 2010, browsers have changed a lot, no answer of that question is even been approved too!

Comment: please avoid linking this question to questions with no clear answer or too old ones. thanks

Comment: @wevra It doesn't mean the *question* is outdated and it's no reason to open a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed. Fix old answers and add new ones to existing questions rather then splitting the information across multiple pages.

Comment: @Boaz so which one should I use? the no 1 top voted answer does not work for linux browsers. no 2 top voted: plugin no longer works. no 3: IE only... people just repeat that link. if they worked i wouldnt bother people's time

Comment: It'a valid question; duplicates are for when the answer is valid and up-to-date. Instead of freaking out over duplicates, what the answer?

Comment: @werva It's not about which answer to use, it's about being part of a community in which if you find answers to be outdated or lacking, you work to improve the current question's page instead of opening a whole new thread for the same question. To get the ball rolling your can research and post a new and improved answer. This will push the question to the front page and get it some new eyes and attention. In such a popular topic it will likely also gain you quite a few upvotes and points. You can also offer a bounty on the original question.

Comment: @Boaz: "your can research and post a new and improved answer"?? No, the OP is not looking to post a new answer, he's asking a question.

Comment: @frenchie First, please let's not turn this into a heated debate. I'm just expressing my opinion, based on the FAQ and common sense. The community will decide if this is a dup or not. Second, the OP clearly states he/she has seen numerous current solutions. This research will be much more helpful as an answer to the original question.

Comment: @Boaz, my question is not the same. I'm looking for a way for modern browsers while in that question, old browsers are important. I want to drop support for those browsers to reach an easy solution. offer a bounty is possible but this is not the same as my question.

Comment: @werva I'm sorry, but the OP in the original question makes no reference to the browser version at all or any kind of backwards compatibility for that matter. Please don't take this personally. This is just a technical matter, and should not be seen as some sort of judgement against you.

Answer (score 1):

javascript cant do [it](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard), security issue for accessing client clipboard, but flash can, and every browser we care about has flash, but flash (thank god) is on the way out, so for now everyone is in flux. flash for now is the only option, but will the powers that be be able to look pass the potential security issues...well wait and see. that's all i know!

Comment: do other websites use flash too?

Comment: i'm not sure what you exactly mean? if you want to access clipboard, you'll be using flash, wrapped in js. there is the [ClipBoard API](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) from W3C but it but hasn't been implemented. flash support on mobile devices will be phased out (this is where the drive to drop flash comes from i think), but who knows how long it will take. until a non-flash solution is agreed upon, you'll have to use it, but at some point in the future it will start breaking for you. if you need it, then run with it, you'll just need to keep on top of what's happening in the market.

Comment: finally I reached this point that the policy of modern browsers is to stop copy to clipboard. so we should avoid that too. although some websites such as tutplus are still using it. it is not standard.

Comment: if your users expect it, want it, or it helps your users be more productive/lazier then do it. it's a convenience feature. features come and go. but if you look at it from a standards point-of-view, there is no standard, just opinions...that's why you are here asking the question. is the maintenance worth the feature? that you will have to answer yourself

Comment: `window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);` does not copy it to clipboard. but the most secure way. you are right. but my rule is to avoid supporting old IE and flash even if client does not like it.